# What is the FileUploadComponent without flash plugin?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I developed a JSF project using mojarra 2.0.2. with facelets as View Description Language.

I used **primefaces 2.2.1** Fileupload Component which uses some kind of flash plugin for the browse button.

That project was developed in windows machine and the browsers supports the flash plugin. But I need to deploy the project in a Linux machine(fedora core 3) which doesn't support the flash plugin. I tried deploying with both firefox 2.0 and opera 10.11.

Both failed to display the browse button Because it uses some flash content. I tried to install the Flash plugin in that machine, but the Linux version is not compatible for the latest flash player(older archives for Linux os Could not be found in the web). It requires infinite dependencies to install which would result in Entire OS Upgrade.

Since I am not permitted to upgrade the OS, I need to find **alternative FileUpload Component** for PrimeFaces component.(I don't prefer to use PF 3.0 SNAPSHOT until it has a stable release. It may have lot of bugs. Despite that, dare I use I).

So my question is " can someone kindly point me towards a `FileUpload Component that does not use Flash Plugin`(with Ajax Functionality) ?"

Thanks...

p.s

The new library should not conflict with PrimeFaces 2.2.1 library.
**Other solutions to this problem also are welcome.** I am open to ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploading files and ajax doesn't go together, that's exactly one of the main reasons why Flash was used. If you can live with uploading files without ajax functionality, then you could grab [Tomahawk's](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/index.html) [`t:inputFileUpload`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_inputFileUpload.html) or create a custom component.You can find [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html) an example based on JSF 2.0 and Servlet 3.0 (Glassfish 3, Tomcat 7, etc).

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you  to check [this](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/fileuploads-with-primefaces-3-0-and-html5/) out

edit: sorry didnt notice that you dont want the 3.0 version

Comment: well someone who might consider to use 3.0 might find this useful don't you think ?